# JAVA PreparedStatement give query in parameter

Tags: java, parameters, prepared-statement

Is there possible to do something like this:

```
String sql2 = "";
if (klases.type == 0) {                
      sql2 = " AND (FIND_IN_SET(id, irasai.pirk_vad) OR FIND_IN_SET(id,irasai.pard_vad))";
}

sql = "SELECT * FROM apmokejimai 
      LEFT JOIN irasai ON apmokejimai.apm_invoice_nr = irasai.invoice_nr 
      WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(?, irasai.pirkejas) OR FIND_IN_SET(?, irasai.pirkejas) IS NULL) 
      ? order by apmokejimai.apm_invoice_nr";

ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, pirk);
ps.setInt(2, pirk);
ps.setString(3, sql2);
```

I want to push some FIND_IN_SET if type is 0 by PreparedStatement parameter, but the problem is that then it sets parameter in query it sets it in '' quotes, is there any way to skip this? Or I just need to use different querys for this? Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try? How would the database prepare the execution plan of the query if half of the query is unknown?

Comment: No. It is not. You must build the complete query in order to prepare a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to preparing the two query and keep in Property file and as per the condition just fetch like:-

```
Property File :-
Query1 = SELECT * FROM apmokejimai LEFT JOIN irasai ON apmokejimai.apm_invoice_nr = irasai.invoice_nr WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(?, irasai.pirkejas) OR FIND_IN_SET(?, irasai.pirkejas) IS NULL) AND (FIND_IN_SET(id, irasai.pirk_vad) OR FIND_IN_SET(id,irasai.pard_vad)) order by apmokejimai.apm_invoice_nr
Query2= SELECT * FROM apmokejimai LEFT JOIN irasai ON apmokejimai.apm_invoice_nr = irasai.invoice_nr WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(?, irasai.pirkejas) OR FIND_IN_SET(?, irasai.pirkejas) IS NULL) order by apmokejimai.apm_invoice_nr

String sql = "";
if (klases.type == 0) {                
    sql = "Get the Query1 from Property File";
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setInt(1, pirk);
    ps.setInt(2, pirk);
    ps.setString(3, sql2);
}else{
    sql = "Get the Query2 from Property File";  
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setInt(1, pirk);
    ps.setInt(2, pirk);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a complete SQL statement that you want to execute for prepare statement. However, this is easy to fix. Use the following SQL:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM apmokejimai 
  LEFT JOIN irasai ON apmokejimai.apm_invoice_nr = irasai.invoice_nr 
  WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(?, irasai.pirkejas) OR FIND_IN_SET(?, irasai.pirkejas) IS NULL) 
   AND (? OR FIND_IN_SET(id, irasai.pirk_vad) OR FIND_IN_SET(id,irasai.pard_vad))
  order by apmokejimai.apm_invoice_nr";
```

Now you can just set `ps.setBoolean(false)` if you want that to be executed or `ps.setBoolean(true)` if you don't want it to be executed.